# Redis client : create new connections when pool size gets exhausted

Tags: spring, redis, connection-pooling, jedis, apache-commons-pool

We are using redis for caching purpose in our application.

Our goal is to create new Redis connections as the pool size exhaust or crosses a certain threshold so that we can keep the number of idle connections minimal . This way a redis-server resource is allocated to a  application-server which really needs it.

In our java application we are using  spring's JedisConnectionFactory of spring-data-redis 1.4.2 which internally uses Jedis 2.6.2 and commons-pool 2.0 .

The latest versions of GenericObjectPool does not have option of growing pool size dynamically. (Earlier versions of commons-pool had whenExhaustAction option)

I also could not find a way to pass a custom object pool in Jedis.

Please suggest how can we achieve this. Does any other Redis-Client has a support for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `maxTotal` property to a negative value, there will be no limit to the number of instances in the pool. You can combine this with a `maxIdle` setting to ensure that there are no more than `maxIdle` idle connections at any given time.